# How to find out the type of a node in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

*Disclaimer: I'm still fairly new to Geometry Nodes, so apologies if I've missed something obvious here...*

Let's say you're taking a look at some of the demo files that are generously hosted on the Blender website, like this [Procedural buildings](https://download.blender.org/demo/geometry-nodes/blender-geometry-nodes_procedural-buildings.blend) example. If you wanted to recreate the Geometry Nodes one after the other, how can you know the "type" of each node? How can I know that one node was created from "Attribute Clamp" for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Reset the node

The Node Wrangler add-on lets you "Reset" the node properties to a clean slate. You have to enable it first in Edit > Preferences > Add-ons :

[image]

Pressing <kbd>backspace</kbd> will remove the node's label and display its base name instead.

You can also go to Node > Reset node [image]

Or click on "Reset Node" in the Node properties in the <kbd>N</kbd> Panel on the node editor's right side.

[image]

You can <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (Undo) afterwards to un-reset the node.

### Remove its label

In the <kbd>N</kbd> Panel on the node editor's right side, navigate to the node properties and delete the text in the label field :

[image]

Notable exceptions : The Math, Vector Math and Boolean nodes automatically have their name changed to their operation (eg Add, Multiply, Greater Than...)

Answer (score 0):

The immediate geometry nodes which you see in this demo sample are already 1 step up in hierarchy, so they were all individually named and consist of groups of geometry nodes themselves.

To expand the view for "initial" geometry nodes, just click on the highlighted symbol.

[image]

and then here to get back to the parent node.

[image]

Comment: But those "child nodes" could still have been renamed at some point. How can you tell something is a "Point Instance" when it was renamed to "FooBar"?